# Build charts from polling JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have a bitcoin miner which can output data in JSON fromat as follows:

```
{
    "Data1": {
        "timestamp_raw": 1442856476,
        "timestamp": {
            "Year": 2015,
            "Month": 9,
            "Day": 21,
            "Hour": 20,
            "Minutes": 27,
            "Seconds": 56
        },
        "CG_Uptime": 15572,
        "MHS_Avg": 2695618.06,
        "DegC_In": "29",
        "DegC_TopOut": "54",
        "DegC_BotOut": "59",
        "Unit_Uptime": 118393,
        "FreeMem": "440",
        "PSUVolt_Top": "217",
        "PSUVolt_Bot": "217",
        "FAN": "40",
        "Total_Watts": 1264,
        "Total_KWh": 0
    },
    "Data2": {
        "timestamp_raw": 1442856495,
        "timestamp": {
            "Year": 2015,
            "Month": 9,
            "Day": 21,
            "Hour": 20,
            "Minutes": 28,
            "Seconds": 15
        },
        "CG_Uptime": 15592,
        "MHS_Avg": 2695948.02,
        "DegC_In": "29",
        "DegC_TopOut": "54",
        "DegC_BotOut": "59",
        "Unit_Uptime": 118412,
        "FreeMem": "440",
        "PSUVolt_Top": "217",
        "PSUVolt_Bot": "217",
        "FAN": "40",
        "Total_Watts": 1248,
        "Total_KWh": 30.006586944
    },
    "Data3": {
        "timestamp_raw": 1442856535,
        "timestamp": {
            "Year": 2015,
            "Month": 9,
            "Day": 21,
            "Hour": 20,
            "Minutes": 28,
            "Seconds": 55
        },
        "CG_Uptime": 15631,
        "MHS_Avg": 2698686.25,
        "DegC_In": "29",
        "DegC_TopOut": "54",
        "DegC_BotOut": "59",
        "Unit_Uptime": 118451,
        "FreeMem": "440",
        "PSUVolt_Top": "217",
        "PSUVolt_Bot": "217",
        "FAN": "40",
        "Total_Watts": 1232,
        "Total_KWh": 0.013688752
    }, ......
```

What I want to do is to make a webpage in php which will read this json file and display the values on charts, x-axis would be time (from timestamp section in json) and y-axis would be a value for each chart.

I've seen something similar here
http://powerprice.info/SPT/graphic.php
which uses highcharts.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is your specific problem? The highcharts API docs have information on how to update charts. What part of that process don't you understand?

Comment: Well I am looking at this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update (I'm not sure if this is the right one for my case). Do I need to somehow poll  the JSON data (say data for the last 24 hours) and store it on my server such that this highchart code can parse it?

Comment: `looking at this` isn't very explanatory in context of the questions

Comment: Sorry typo, corrected my response

Comment: probably don't need to store it if the api gives you time ranges as direct response, not sure if api is CORS enabled or if you need to use a php proxy on your server either. If use php proxy all it would do is get the data from api and send it right back out to the ajax request

Comment: Using php on my server wouldn't be a problem, I'm just looking for a way to implement this

Comment: look for ajax examples in highcharts docs

Comment: I don't see how to make the charts remember the JSON value's history. Trying to use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() in a php scripts that runs in crontab..

Comment: Really can't help since you haven't provided much info regarding the api and how it works or what php code you are using

Comment: Let me know, why you cannot load json with data, and then load new points dynamically, by using setInteraval and addPoint? Using ob_start() seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: I updated my question, I now have timestamps in my json file so I just need to read the json file and display the data on charts, x-axis will be time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking just for a general advice.

**Live data:**

Here is mine: If server, which provides you data for bitcoins supports history data, like specific requests with data range (from-to etc.) then, simply use AJAX call in the HTML file to your server. Then call some GET/POST to the providers server in PHP  to get requested data. Then in AJAX response provide data to the chart. Just make sure you have proper format, required by Highcharts.

You will not find many examples on the Highcharts site, because it really doesn't matter for Highcharts what you have in the backend. However, [this tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) explains a little bit. In step `#1: Set up the server` instead of randomized data, get proper data from your data provider.

**Preprocessing data:**

Additional advice, according to your question update: I can't tell you how you need to store data for last week, but I guess simple database would be enough. As you said, use some cron task, to get data from the service, then store it in your database.

The question is which property of your JSON is value to be displayed on the chart. In example below, I assume that `MHS_Avg` is used as y-values. I don't see anything to be x-value (like date or timestamp), though.

Let's say you have `/var/www/json.php` do load data for the chart:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/var/www/json.php", function (data) {
        var value,
        series = [{
            name: "MHS_Avg",
            data: []
        }]; // create series array with all series

        // now parse data:
        $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
            value = parseFloat(obj["MHS_Avg"]);
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                series[0].data.push([i, value]);
                // or:
                // series[0].data.push(value);
                // or:
                // series[0].data.push({ x: i, y: value });
            };
        });

        // create chart
        $('#temps_hist').highcharts({
            series: series
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: And updated answer. Note: I'm not PHP-guy, so getting data from database in PHP is not my part. Of course, there is hundreds of similar questions on SO (about PHP+MySQL etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! X-axis would be time, so I would need to produce a new json with an extra field for its timestamp. I'll work on it and will be back with results.